# Parsing multiple child nodes of XML in TCL using expat

Tags: xml, tcl

I have provided a short XML document at the bottom of my code, this is exactly what I need to parse, except with 10 parameters, and about 10,000 "cmds". I am parsing the document, and writing it to a .txt file. I'm printing the values of the nodes into the .txt as such:

```
CMD_ID     Param_1_Name     Param_1_Value     Param_N_Name     Param_N_Value ...
```

The script seems to be only printing the very last parameter name and value, rather than each. I assume there needs to be a foreach loop implemented, but I'm lost as to where it should be. Here is my TCL script:

```tcl
 package require tdom
 proc parse xml {
    set ::S {};                 # Global stack ::S maintained to track tag hierarchy
    set p [expat -elementstartcommand els \
                 -characterdatacommand  ch \
                 -elementendcommand  ele ]
    if [catch {$p parse $xml} res] {
        puts "Error: $res" ;            # Error catch and put   
    }
 }
#---- Callbacks for start, end, character data
 proc els {name atts} {
    lappend ::S $name ;             # PUSH - els pushes current tag name
    if {$name eq "cmd"} {array unset ::g};  # When cmd element ends, g reset
 }
 proc ele name {
    global g
    set ::S [lrange $::S 0 end-1] ;     # POP - ele pops current tag name
    if {$name eq "cmd"} {
            puts $g(id)\t$g(name)\t$g(value)
    }
 }
 proc ch str {  ;               # Collects the content of elements in global array g
    global g
    set type [lindex $::S end]
    switch -- $type {
        id - name - value {set g($type) $str}
    }
 }
#-- Test parser on command below:
 parse "
<cmds>
    <cmd>
        <id>CMD_ID_1</id>
        <params>
            <param>
                <name>Param_1</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_2</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_3</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_4</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
        </params>
    </cmd>
        <cmd>
        <id>CMD_ID_2</id>
        <params>
            <param>
                <name>Param_1</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_2</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_3</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_4</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
        </params>
    </cmd>
</cmds>"
```

The output is:

```
CMD_ID_1     Param_4      ON/OFF
CMD_ID_2     Param_4      ON/OFF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way:

On line 20 inside `ele`, replace

```
puts $g(id)\t$g(name)\t$g(value)
```

with

```
    foreach name $g(name) value $g(value) {
        puts $g(id)\t$name\t$value
    }
```

And on line 27 inside `ch`, replace

```
    id - name - value {set g($type) $str}
```

with

```
    id - name - value {lappend g($type) $str}
```

The `set` command overwrites earlier values, `lappend` collects them. Then you only need to iterate over those values to print them out.

---

**addendum**

The following code simplifies your logic somewhat and works for your test data at least:

```
proc parse xml {
    global data
    set p [expat -characterdatacommand ch -elementendcommand ele]
    $p parse $xml
    dict for {id values} $data {
        foreach {name value} $values {
            puts $id\t$name\t$value
        }
    }
}

proc ele name {
    global data idx str
    switch $name {
        id {
            set idx $str
        }
        name -
        value {
            dict lappend data $idx $str
        }
    }
}

proc ch data {
    global str
    set str $data
}
```

(Note that this code is depending on the `name` elements always preceding the `value` elements. It's quite possible, but a little more involved, to make the code independent of that.)

---

**addendum 2**

Globals are icky. An object-oriented solution is neater:

```
package require tdom

oo::class create ParserHelper {
    variable p str idx data
    constructor args {
        set data {}
        set p [expat \
            -characterdatacommand [namespace code {my characterdata}] \
            -elementendcommand [namespace code {my elementend}]]
    }
    destructor {
        catch {$p free}
    }
    method parse xml {
        $p reset
        $p parse $xml
    }
    method characterdata s {
        set str $s
    }
    method elementend {s args} {
        switch $s {
            id {
                set idx $str
            }
            name -
            value {
                dict lappend data $idx $str
            }
        }
    }
    method puts {} {
        dict for {id values} $data {
            foreach {name value} $values {
                puts $id\t$name\t$value
            }
        }
    }
}

ParserHelper create ph
ph parse $xml
ph puts
```

I'll stop tinkering with this now...

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm), [my](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/my.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [oo::class](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/class.htm), [oo::define](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm)

Comment: Thank you, that foreach loop was exactly what I needed! It print out beautifully. I appreciate the OO solution as well, I'll try both variations and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the array each time in the following code

```
# Here, you are overwriting the 'type' variable index of array
switch -- $type {
        id - name - value {set g($type) $str}
}
```

Thus the last entries alone retained.

Instead, you can maintain an array where the indices are prefixed with the command name, like

```
CMD_ID_1,name
CMD_ID_1,value
.
.
.
CMD_ID_N,name
CMD_ID_N,value
```

And with each index, append the names and values... like,

```
::g(CMD_ID_1,name)  = Param_1 Param_2 Param_3 Param_4
::g(CMD_ID_1,value) = ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF
::g(CMD_ID_2,name)  = Param_1 Param_2 Param_3 Param_4
::g(CMD_ID_2,value) = ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF
```

One last thing you should do is to keep track of the command names. So, just have a variable to hold the names of the commands and you can loop the array with the prefix of the variable.

**extractXMLInfo.tcl**

```
package require tdom
 proc parse xml {
    set ::S {};                 # Global stack ::S maintained to track tag hierarchy
    set p [expat -elementstartcommand els \
                 -characterdatacommand  ch \
                 -elementendcommand  ele ]
    if [catch {$p parse $xml} res] {
        puts "Error: $res" ;            # Error catch and put   
    }
 }
#---- Callbacks for start, end, character data
 proc els {name atts} {
    lappend ::S $name ;             # PUSH - els pushes current tag name
    # No need of the below statement - Dinesh 
    #if {$name eq "cmd"} {array unset ::g};  # When cmd element ends, g reset
 }
 proc ele name {
    global g
    set ::S [lrange $::S 0 end-1] ;     # POP - ele pops current tag name

    # No need of the below statement - Dinesh 
    # if {$name eq "cmd"} {
            # puts $g(id)\t$g(name)\t$g(value)
    # }
 }
 proc ch str { 
    global g
    set type [lindex $::S end]
    set current_cmd_name {}
    switch -- $type {
        id {
            if {[lsearch $::cmd_id $str]==-1} {
                lappend ::cmd_id $str
            }
        }
        name - 
        value {
            set current_cmd_name [lindex $::cmd_id end]
            if {$current_cmd_name eq {}} {
                puts "ERROR : No command name found"
            } else {
                lappend g($current_cmd_name,$type) $str
            }
        }
    }
 }

# Variable to track the command's names.
set ::cmd_id {}
array set ::g {}
 parse "
<cmds>
    <cmd>
        <id>CMD_ID_1</id>
        <params>
            <param>
                <name>Param_1</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_2</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_3</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_4</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
        </params>
    </cmd>
        <cmd>
        <id>CMD_ID_2</id>
        <params>
            <param>
                <name>Param_1</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_2</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_3</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>Param_4</name>
                <value>ON/OFF</value>
            </param>
        </params>
    </cmd>
</cmds>"
parray ::g
puts "cmd_ids : $::cmd_id"
# Looping through the commands and printing the 
# name and value pairs
foreach cmd $::cmd_id {
    puts =========================================
    puts "Command : $cmd"
    foreach name $::g($cmd,name) value $::g($cmd,value) {
        puts "$name = $value"
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
::g(CMD_ID_1,name)  = Param_1 Param_2 Param_3 Param_4
::g(CMD_ID_1,value) = ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF
::g(CMD_ID_2,name)  = Param_1 Param_2 Param_3 Param_4
::g(CMD_ID_2,value) = ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF ON/OFF
cmd_ids : CMD_ID_1 CMD_ID_2
=========================================
Command : CMD_ID_1
Param_1 = ON/OFF
Param_2 = ON/OFF
Param_3 = ON/OFF
Param_4 = ON/OFF
=========================================
Command : CMD_ID_2
Param_1 = ON/OFF
Param_2 = ON/OFF
Param_3 = ON/OFF
Param_4 = ON/OFF
```

Comment: This is a great way to keep track of the command names. The formatting looks great on the output as well, thank you for the recommendations!